# In Material Preview is it possible to render only scene lights and not textures of objects?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, lighting

When trying to place lights in a scene it can be frustrating when Material Preview (Lookdev) mode is lagging when there are a lot objects with a lot of textures, transparencies etc. Often when you switch to this mode there is a brief lag where, it displays the objects as MatCaps, but with the lights bouncing and casting shadows. But then eventually it processes the texutures and everything slows down which can make it difficult to place lights accurately for a desired look.

Is it possible to switch off the textures in Material preview and just render light and shadow with a Matcap on the objects?

Thank you.